# is it possible to reverse mysql aes_encrypt to find the key?

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

The title says it all, i have a clear text password and a blob data in a mysql column representing it which is most likely to be AES encrypted. So is it possible to reverse it to get the AES key ?

Answer (score 2):

No, [there are no known key recovery attacks on AES.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3952/is-it-possible-to-obtain-aes-128-key-from-a-known-ciphertext-plaintext-pair)

If the encryption scheme uses AES incorrectly (e.g. with a fixed IV), then it may be possible to obtain enough information from a known ciphertext/plaintext pair to be able to decrypt other ciphertext pairs encrypted with the same scheme.  Even then, however, such an attack won't actually give you the AES key.

The amount of information that can be obtained using such attacks depends on the encryption mode and on the number and size of the known ciphertext/plaintext pairs, but in general, any setup that does not use a unique (and preferably random) IV for each encrypted blob [is likely to be at least somewhat vulnerable.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2576/encryption-with-constant-initialization-vector-considered-harmful)  For example, using a fixed IV with CTR or OFB mode is an extremely bad idea, as it lets an attacker decrypt *everything* based on just a single sufficiently long known ciphertext/plaintext pair.  CBC and CFB modes fail somewhat less catastrophically, but they'll also leak information if the same IV is reused (and for CBC mode, also if an attacker can get their own messages encrypted with an IV they can predict in advance).